# Making variations of \boxed

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I have to typeset certain formulas, and the notation involves stretchable boxes, pretty much like `\boxed{X}` makes, but occasionally I need to add a hat below and/or above, as the picture shows:

[image: A fancy box]

(Symbols in this fancy box should be on the baseline.)

I usually find anything I want in "The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List", but this time I think it's too special. Any ideas how I can implement this?

Thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution using `tikz` with lots of configuration options:

- `above`: draw hat above box
- `below`: draw hat below box
- `rule`: line thickness
- `sep`: distance between contents and frame (`inner sep`/`\fboxsep`)
- `height`: height of the hat
- `drawcolor`: color of the lines/frame/hat
- `textcolor`: color of the text/math inside the frame
- `mathstyle`: math style, default is `\displaystyle` as in `\boxed` of `amsmath`
- `bold`: make math bold (`\boldmath`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{kvoptions}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=boxedhat,
  prefix=boxedhat@,
  setkeys=\kvsetkeys,
}
\newcommand*{\boxedhatsetup}{\kvsetkeys{boxedhat}}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{above}
\DeclareBoolOption[true]{below}
\DeclareBoolOption[false]{bold}
\DeclareStringOption[\fboxsep]{sep}
\DeclareStringOption[\fboxrule]{rule}
\DeclareStringOption[1ex]{height}
\DeclareStringOption[\displaystyle]{mathstyle}
\DeclareStringOption[]{drawcolor}
\DeclareStringOption[.]{textcolor}

\newsavebox\boxedhat@box
\newcommand*{\boxedhat}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \boxedhatsetup{#1}%
    \tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
      \draw[draw={\boxedhat@drawcolor}]
        let
          \n{sep}={\boxedhat@sep},
          \n{rule}={\boxedhat@rule}
        in
          [line width=\n{rule}]
          node[
            rectangle,
            draw,
            inner sep=\n{sep},
            text={\boxedhat@textcolor},
          ] (X) {%
            \global\setbox\boxedhat@box=\hbox{%
              \begingroup % because of \boldmath and color
                \m@th
                \ifboxedhat@bold
                  \boldmath
                \fi
                $\boxedhat@mathstyle#2$%
              \endgroup
            }%
            \copy\boxedhat@box
          }
        \pgfextra{%
          \def\width{\wd\boxedhat@box}%
          \def\height{\ht\boxedhat@box}%
          \def\depth{\dp\boxedhat@box}%
          \def\totalheight{\dimexpr\ht\boxedhat@box+\dp\boxedhat@box\relax}%
        }%
        let
          \n{hatheight}={\boxedhat@height},
          \p{ul}=($(X.north west) + (.5*\n{rule},0)$),
          \p{uc}=(X.north),
          \p{ur}=($(X.north east) + (-.5*\n{rule},0)$),
          \p{top}=(\x{uc}, \y{uc} + \n{hatheight}),
          \p{ll}=($(X.south west) + (.5*\n{rule},0)$),
          \p{lc}=(X.south),
          \p{lr}=($(X.south east) + (-.5*\n{rule},0)$),
          \p{bottom}=(\x{lc}, \y{lc} - \n{hatheight})
        in
          \ifboxedhat@above
            (\p{ll}) -- (\p{ul}) -- (\p{top}) -- (\p{ur}) -- (\p{lr})
          \fi
          \ifboxedhat@below
            (\p{ul}) -- (\p{ll}) -- (\p{bottom}) -- (\p{lr}) -- (\p{ur})
          \fi
      ;%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\boxedhatsetup{sep=.75\fboxsep}

\begin{document}
\[
  \boxedhat[above=false, drawcolor=blue]{x}
  < \boxedhat[rule=1pt,sep=1ex,bold,height=.5\height+1ex]{y'}
  = \boxedhat[textcolor=red]{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}
  < \boxedhat[below=false, drawcolor=blue]{z}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks great and that's what I had in mind. I used to draw everything in MetaPost, so I am not familiar with TikZ.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an option with [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); each one of the three commands `\Hatup`, `\Hatdown`, and `\Hatupdown` has an optional argument allowing you to use the features provided by the package to control the attributes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  up/.style={
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=\fboxsep,
    right=\fboxsep,
    top=\fboxsep,
    bottom=\fboxsep,
    overlay={\draw[\kvtcb@colframe,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule] (frame.north west) -- ([yshift=1ex]$ (frame.north west)!0.5!(frame.north east) $ ) -- (frame.north east);}
  },
  down/.style={
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=\fboxsep,
    right=\fboxsep,
    top=\fboxsep,
    bottom=\fboxsep,
    overlay={\draw[\kvtcb@colframe,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule] (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=-1ex]$ (frame.south west)!0.5!(frame.south east) $ ) -- (frame.south east);}
  },
  updown/.style={
    enhanced,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=\fboxsep,
    right=\fboxsep,
    top=\fboxsep,
    bottom=\fboxsep,
    overlay={
      \draw[\kvtcb@colframe,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule] (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=-1ex]$ (frame.south west)!0.5!(frame.south east) $ ) -- (frame.south east);
      \draw[\kvtcb@colframe,line width=\kvtcb@left@rule] (frame.north west) -- ([yshift=1ex]$ (frame.north west)!0.5!(frame.north east) $ ) -- (frame.north east);}
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\Hatup[2][]{\tcbhighmath[up,#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\Hatdown[2][]{\tcbhighmath[down,#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\Hatupdown[2][]{\tcbhighmath[updown,#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
a = \Hatup{b + c^{2}}\quad 
a = \Hatdown{b + c^{2}}\quad
a = \Hatupdown{b + c^{2}}
\]

\begin{align*}
\Hatup[colframe=red!80!black,boxrule=1pt]{\int x^{2}\,\textrm{d}x = \frac{1}{3} x^{3} + c} &= \Hatup{\sum_{i=i}^{n}a_{i}} 
\\[1ex]
\Hatupdown[coltext=orange]{\int x^{2}\,\textrm{d}x = \frac{1}{3} x^{3} + c} &= \Hatdown[colframe=cyan,boxrule=1pt]{\sum_{i=i}^{n}a_{i}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks just for fun as usual.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\psset{linewidth=\fboxrule}
\newcommand\mybox[2][4pt]{%
    \psDefBoxNodes{A}{\fbox{#2}}%
    \pspolygon(A:tl)([offset=#1]A:tC)(A:tr)(A:br)([offset=-#1]A:bC)(A:bl)}

\begin{document}
\mybox{Weirdstress Function}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Miscellaneous

Anything can be boxed.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\psset{linewidth=\fboxrule}
\newcommand\mybox[2][4pt]{%
    \psDefBoxNodes{A}{\fbox{#2}}%
    \pspolygon(A:tl)([offset=#1]A:tC)(A:tr)(A:br)([offset=-#1]A:bC)(A:bl)}

\begin{document}
\mybox[6pt]{\parbox{4cm}{The Weirdstress function, \[\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \tan (b^k \pi x)\] in action.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Is it possible to add math equations/symbols inside box like above examples

Comment: @texenthusiast: yes of course, anything can be boxed.

Comment: In my opinion the requested top or bottom hat does not look aesthetically good no matter who creates the box. Sorry for this opinion and thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 3):

I use `stackengine` to place the "hats" (I actually use triangles) above and below the item.  I use `\scalerel` to stretch them.  The length `\trihite` determines the height of the triangle hats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\usepackage{cmll}
\newlength\trihite
\setlength\trihite{8.8889pt}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\boxwidth
\newcommand\underhat[1]{%
  \fboxrule .5pt%
  \sbox\mybox{\framebox{$#1$}}%
  \setlength\boxwidth{\wd\mybox}%
  \mathop{\stackunder[-2.2pt]{\framebox{$#1$}}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\bigtriangledown}{1.15\boxwidth}}{\the\trihite}}}%
}
\newcommand\overhat[1]{%
  \fboxrule .5pt%
  \sbox\mybox{\framebox{$#1$}}%
  \setlength\boxwidth{\wd\mybox}%
  \mathop{\stackon[-2.3pt]{\framebox{$#1$}}{%
    \stretchto{\scaleto{\bigtriangleup}{1.15\boxwidth}}{\the\trihite}}}%
}
\newcommand\overunderhat[1]{%
  \fboxrule .5pt%
  \sbox\mybox{\framebox{$#1$}}%
  \setlength\boxwidth{\wd\mybox}%
  \mathop{\stackunder[-2.2pt]{%
    \stackon[-2.3pt]{\framebox{$#1$}}{%
      \stretchto{\scaleto{\bigtriangleup}{1.15\boxwidth}}{\the\trihite}}%
  }{%
      \stretchto{\scaleto{\bigtriangledown}{1.15\boxwidth}}{\the\trihite}}}%
}
\begin{document}
$\underhat{xxx} x \overhat{xxxxx} y \overunderhat{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Tweaked!